# jQuery load() overwrite

Tags: jquery

I have some problems with `load()` functions.

I have a `collection.html` page, in this page I have a image slaider. All works perfect, but when I load other page, and then go back to `collection.html` slaider, some of images divs has previous settings, for example

```
<div class="image active">
</div>
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="image active">
</div>
<div class="image">
</div>
```

If I click on menu more times, load functions keep previus data on memory.

How to create that, if I click on collection.html link, that calls load functions, each time start loading from beggining, not to from previus state?

Here is click event:

```
$('.menu ul li.collection_link a').click(function(){
        $('.menu ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(".height").css("height","750px");
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#primary").fadeOut("fast", function () {
            $("#primary").load(link, {
                limit: 25
            }, function(){
                $("#primary").fadeIn("fast");
            });
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: How did you initialize the slider?

Comment: it's tricky to understand without html-code example

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the back button issue, why don't you clear the active class on document ready?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu ul li').removeClass('active');
});
```